# How to move to a different section of code

Tags: python-3.7

new python programmer, looking for a fix for this issue. I'm making an autofill rubric for a school project, how would I move to a different section of my code. For example, I want to be able to re-run this function, but that breaks my input because I cannot put it into the function itself.

```
#TODO...
#Add students names in IN the code, same with num of students

numberOfStudents = 4

rubrick = ["Preparedness", "Engagement", "Perseverance", "Problem Solving", "Progessionalism"]
students = ["ROBERT", "DEVIN", "SKYLER", "XAVIER"]

def pickStudent():
    print('Please select your student...')

    for x in range(len(students)):
        print(students[x])


pickStudent()
userPicked = input().upper()

if userPicked == students[0]:
    print("You picked... " + students[0])

elif userPicked == students [1]:
    print("You picked... " + students[1])

elif userPicked == students [2]:
    print("You picked... " + students[2])

elif userPicked == students [3]:
    print("You picked... " + students[3])
else:
    print("Invalid user... \n")
    pickStudent()
    userPicked = input().upper()
```

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: Look into loops in Python. You need one here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things to pick out here.

You probably want to put the user picking in a `while` loop to ensure it keeps asking until a correct answer is given.

You also don't need to test the entry against each item in the list in turn - instead use the `in` operator to see if the inputted text is found ion the list.

Combining these gives you:

```
while userPicked not in students:
  userPicked = input().upper()
```

Instead of looping over students to print them, you can write neater code using `join` - to join all the items in the `students` list into a string and print that:

```
print('\n'.join(students))
```